# GroupStyle Property

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image]

I have a datagrid with 2 groups, 1 with no header and the other one is Subtractions. I want to get rid of the small space at the leftmost part of the grid(highlighted with red). Which property do I need to set? I've been fiddling around the available properties in GroupStyle with no success.

Comment: Do you want to share the style with us to avoid guessing?

Comment: The code is very long and it will a bit of time to take it apart. Anyway, I found a hack to make it work. I've set the left margin of the DataGridRowsPresenter to -5. The property I'm looking for is padding but the DataGridRowsPresenter doesn't have that property.